# Buffer over-run prevention for stack based buffers

Tags: c, arrays, buffer-overflow

I'm writing a C library that provides wrapper functions to strcpy, strcat, gets, etc to prevent buffer overflow attacks. Basically what I do is keeping track of the size of all buffers and prevent from writing beyond the allocated memory. I'm able to keep track of dynamically allocated buffers by writing a wrappers for malloc, calloc and realloc. But I couldn't get the size of buffer in stack.

```
char s[10];
char *s1 = "stackoverflow";
strcpy(s,s1);
```

The call to 'strcpy' in the above code would call my wrapper function which looks like

```
char *strcpy(char* s1, const char* s2)
```

Since the function takes the source as char*, I'm unable to know the size of the source array which is in the stack. I tried reallocating the stack based buffer and my program crashed. Is reallocating the buffer a viable solution for this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't get the size of globals either, or the size of arrays inside a structure. Example: `struct person { char name[28]; int age }` - `malloc` may know that it allocated 32 bytes, but `strcpy` cannot use those 32 bytes for the name.

Comment: You can't don that. The only way to prevent buffer overflows is not using `strcpy`-like functions, but replacing them by equivalent functions where you pass explicitly the size of the destination buffer. E.g. `secure_strcpy(s, s1, buffersize);`

Comment: Think about it - if it was that easy, someone would already have done it.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the function takes the source as char*, I'm unable to know the
>   size of the source array which is in the stack.

`char *` is a generic pointer, you can cast your source to another type.

An example using a compound literal and a `struct`:

```
struct secure {
    char *s;
    size_t sz;
};

#define SECURE(xs, xsz) (char *)&((struct secure){.s = xs, .sz = xsz})

char *strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    struct secure *sec = (struct secure *)s1;

    if (sec->sz < strlen(s2)) {
        printf("%s\n", "stackoverflow");
    } else {
        yourimplementation(sec->s, s2);
    }
    return sec->s;
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[10];
    char *s1 = "stackoverflow";

    strcpy(SECURE(s, sizeof s - 1), s1);
    return 0;
}
```

You can avoid using `SECURE` in the call in this way:

```
struct secure {
    char *s;
    size_t sz;
};

#define SECURE(ps, psz) (char *)&((struct secure){.s = ps, .sz = psz})
#define strcpy(s1, s2) strcpy(SECURE(s1, sizeof s1 - 1), s2)

char *(strcpy)(char *s1, const char *s2) /* () to distinguish from macro */
{
    struct secure *sec = (struct secure *)s1;

    if (sec->sz < strlen(s2)) {
        printf("%s\n", "stackoverflow");
    } else {
        yourimplementation(sec->s, s2);
    }
    return sec->s;
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[10];
    char *s1 = "stackoverflow";

    strcpy(s, s1);
    return 0;
}
```

But this will not work with dynamic memory (`sizeof` pointer is not what you want)

Answer (score 1):

Here `s` is automatic storage, and `realloc` is meant to reallocate the dynamic allocated memory by calling `malloc` or other allocatin functions. So you cannot call `realloc` on `s`, calling it would results UB, so crash is no surprise.

So even if you find a way to get the size of automatic variables you won't be able to resize it, the only thing you can do is make a whole new buffer and then copy old buffer into the new one. But in that case, you will need a flag to distinguish between dynamic storage and automatic ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can not know the buffersize from just having char * pointer. For this reason many libraries implements their own string objects. Examples: GString in glib, PHP has its internal String object, pascal language uses a string object.

Answer (score 0):

You are tackling a common problem in an interesting and more automated way.

The GCC itself hat a stack protector which crashes the program if somebody wrote to unallowed areas, whether intentionally or not. It places certain variables on the stack with defined values und if these values change the stack corruption can be detected.

When handling char pointer within functions there's no way to know how much memory the area pointed to has. You could design your own "char" class/struct which handles that for you by keeping your char pointer and it's size together.

```
struct char_helper {
     int size;
     char data[];
}

char buffer[10+sizeof(struct char_helper)]:
struct char_helper *mychar = (struct char_helper*)buffer;
mychar.size = 76;
your_strcpy(mychar, "hallo", 6);
```

Your function `your_strcpy` now can check the size. Technically I prepended an integer for the size. Another and more flexible way would be to just tell strcpy which size the buffer has it shall copy to...

That's what `strncpy`, `snprintf`, `strnlen` do. They have a little quirk with terminating 0 characters though.